# Changing UAC for child account on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, uac

Is there a way to change the UAC settings on windows 10 for a Microsoft Family Child account?  If I log in as that child, I can access the UAC settings but can't alter them (a child account is a standard account) which makes sense.

But if I log in as an administrator, I can only modify my own UAC settings, there doesn't seem to be any way to modify another users' UAC.

I'd like to give the child account the ability to install applications, but not modify accounts, services, etc.

Comment: “I'd like to give the child account the ability to install applications, but not modify accounts, services, etc” That’s just not possible.

Comment: I answered your question, but I suggest telling what your case is and what exactly you want to achieve (allow/disallow something) so maybe you could find another solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this:

> Is there a way to change the UAC settings on windows 10 for a Microsoft Family Child account?

**No, because UAC settings are global.**

---

As explained in the UAC settings in windows:

> User Account Control helps prevent potentially harmful programs from making changes to your **computer**.

The description states it's for the computer, and not the current account.

And also, the registry settings related to UAC are sitting under `HKLM` and not `HKCU`, so they're not user specific.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible given they are a global setting.

That said, this will not make a difference even if it were per user settings. To install programs you simply need more than to click a box from an UAC dialog. You need rights too. Administrative rights, or modify rights on the location the program wants to install, depending on the setup. Some programs install more than just files on the harddrive. They can actually modify the system, such as install a service. In this case, Administrative rights are always required. Simple games could be managed through steam. If you make the Steam folder modifyable by the account of your child, he should be able to install games from steam without needing any Administrative rights.